# Blank Column Name required in Excel generation c#

Tags: c#, excel

In C# i am passing datatable to a function to generate excel

```
SpreadsheetGear.IRange range = sheet1.Cells[1, 0, 3, columnCount];
range.CopyFromDataTable(dt, SpreadsheetGear.Data.SetDataFlags.InsertCells);
```

I want my column name as blank in excel generated,Tried to rename column of datatable using this this

```
dt.Columns["Sno"].ColumnName = "";
```

for the same,but it ended with an exception.
To be more specific i had columns in datatable,but now i want column name as blank in excel i am generating.
Please help in resolving this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the following exception:

> ColumnName is required when it is part of a DataTable

So I guess that tells you everything, the ColumnName needs to be something. I was able to get it working providing one space: `" "`

```
dt.Columns["Sno"].ColumnName = " ";
```

Is that an option for you?